# Creating Web-to-Lead for more than two salesforce instance

Tags: leads, html, php, web2lead, post

I want to use one web-to-lead form to send data to my two salesforce instances at once. Meaning I need to use two URLs for POST action and two "oid" in the form.
Is it possible and if it how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't easily do this in the browser, so you would want to do this in your server script.

Comment: @sfdcfox by server script you mean my website where I am going to deploy this form?

Comment: yes, you could write this logic into your php script.

Comment: and if I need to it in my browser how can I do it, by allowing CORS?
@sfdcfox